# How can I assign a block to a panel or mini-panel?

Tags: panels

I was reading the project description for [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and I noticed it was a way—using mini-panels—for me to rearrange the contents of my site.

So I just created a mini-panel with a two column layout. I want to add one block to the left and one block to the right. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Mini panels are blocks and you can add Mini Panels to Panels. You can't add blocks themselves to Panels, but usually most of the **content** that you can display in a block, you can actually display in Panels, content such as Activities, Menus, Mini panels themselves, Miscellaneous, Pages elements, Views, Widgets, Nodes, Custom content and more.

See [Drupal - Blocks vs Context vs Panels](http://www.slideshare.net/davexoxide/drupal-blocks-vs-context-vs-panels).

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom blocks to mini-panels. So create a custom block on the block admin page - admin/structure/block - and then add to your mini-panel or panel.

Comment: Can you not add normal blocks? Such as exposed filters?